# Why does Eclipse run the installed app instead of building new apk after making changes?

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I have an Android project with a couple of Java-only projects as dependencies.
I made changes to one of the Java-only projects, saved.
I have "Build Automatically" checked.

I hit Run > (Android application target)

The console in Eclipse shows that it's sending the start Intent to my app, the app starts on the attached phone.

I expect that it would know that something has changed in the project, re-build it and all projects dependent on it, upload the resulting .apk to the phone, and only then send the start Intent.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: It rebuilds an apk. See in the bin folder. After every chnage and compiling. Why? Isn't it working for you?

Comment: I don't know if there are particular settings that can make it automatically, but I usually just do a clean on the android project. Actually a good question... +1

Comment: @Ahmad I thought I made it clear in the question that this isn't working for me :P